# How to delete rows if repeated more than 5 times?

Tags: r

I'm really desperately looking for an answer.
I have only one column with duplicated IDs.
I want to have this kind of code:

```
ID
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
b
```

so if there are 6 a's, the 6th row should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of options.  Grouped by the 'ID' column, `slice` the first 5 rows (with `head` and `row_number()`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(head(row_number(), 5))
```

or with `filter` to create a logical expression based on `row_number()` after grouping by the 'ID' column

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(row_number() < 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `ave` with `seq_along` and `subset`  for each `ID`.

```
subset(df, ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along) <= 5)

#   ID
#1   a
#2   a
#3   a
#4   a
#5   a
#7   b
#8   b
#9   b
#10  b
#11  b
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```